# C# - Read from MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, file, download

I have a db in MySQL that is connected to a c# code.
As part of my code I'd like to download files from my db to a folder in the c# project, and I want it to work for multiple type of files (csv,pcap and lua)
my database looks like so :
[image]

In my C# Code my function is supposed to get the column(which is what file are we after , for example "lua_file" ,"pcap_file"...) and the column_name which is basically the column with the name of that file.
my problem is how can I add it as generic values to the select statement ? In addition I have a parameter which is called p_name who holds what protocol in my table I wanna check(there might be a couple different protocols)

**C# CODE**

```
 public static void ReadFromDB(string column , string column_name)
    {
        try
        {
            string cmd_str;
            MySqlDataAdapter Da_Obj = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            MySqlCommand Cm_Obj = new MySqlCommand();
            DataSet FilesDB = new DataSet();

            cmd_str = "SELECT lua_name,lua_file FROM filesdb WHERE protocol_name ='" + p_name + "';";
            Da_Obj = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd_str, connection);
            connection.Open();
            Da_Obj.Fill(FilesDB, "filesdb");

            Cm_Obj = new MySqlCommand(cmd_str, connection);
            MySqlDataReader reader = Cm_Obj.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read() && reader != null)
            {
                Byte[] bytes;
                bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Empty);
                bytes = (Byte[])reader["lua_file"];
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(MainWindow.output_folder + FilesDB.Tables["filesdb"].Rows[0]["lua_name"].ToString(),
                    FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                fs.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Download Completed!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Failed in ReadFromDB!");
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: So you want to replace the _lua_name_ and _lua_file_ in the select statement with another set of two columns depending on some conditions? Then just pass a flag to the function and decide between the two statements you want and use the index of the column to read it instead of the name. And as already said, do not concatenate strings to build sql commands

Comment: By the way, creating an adapter and filling it is useless if then you start a loop to read with a datareader

Comment: @Steve What do you mean by "pass a flag?" I'm passing the names I want to read from as the params to my function but as the guy above u said I'm trying to change it to parameterized queries , is it possible to do so for the column names ? so it'll be sort of generic input ?

Comment: No, column names cannot be parameterized. Usually it is never a great idea to write a generic function to read database data. A better solution are ORM libraries ranging from the big ones like EntityFramework to the smaller and faster like Dapper. If you really insist in writing a "Read_it_All" function then at least be sure that your column names are taken from a white list of allowable names and not directly from the user input